# How to Run a Python file from Java using an Absolute Path?

Tags: java, python

I want to run a python script called, for example foo. And I have the absoulute path, lets say:
    /Users/me/pythonscripts/

I have tried running:

```
String cmd="/Users/me/pythonscripts/"
String py="foo"
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd "+cmd);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python "+py+".py");
```

But that does run the python file.

Comment: Check the following link : http://norwied.wordpress.com/2012/03/28/call-python-script-from-java-app/

Comment: You might also look at [jython](http://www.jython.org) which will jun python scripts on the Java VM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using something more like...

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python "+cmd + py + ".py");
```

Instead.  Each `exec` is it's own process and multiple `exec` has no relationship to each other...

You should also consider using `ProcessBuilder` instead, as this provides you with a great level of configurability, for example, you can change the execution path context...

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", py + ".py");
pb.directory(new File(cmd));
pb.redirectError();
//...
Process p = pb.start();
```

Also, beware, that Python has an issue with it's output stream, which may prevent Java from reading it until it's completely finished if at all...

For more details, take a look at [Java: is there a way to run a system command and print the output during execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102989/java-is-there-a-way-to-run-a-system-command-and-print-the-output-during-executi/19103198#19103198)

Also, make sure `python` is within the shell's search path, otherwise you will need to specify the full path to the command as well

Comment: Thanks for the ProcessBuilder tip, super helpful! Works great now.

Comment: It just didn't execute the python file, not sure what the issue was there. I commented a bit prematurely though, I made this work great with process builder.

Answer (score 1):

this work for me

```
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException{

    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p1 = runtime.exec("D:\\programs\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\spyder.exe \"C:\\Users\\Al-Hanouf\\codes\\PageRank.py\"");
    System.out.print("is process alive = "+p1.isAlive());

}
```