# Running a .py file from Java

Tags: java, python

I am trying to execute a .py file from java code. I move the .py file in the default dir of my java project and I call it using the following code:

```
    String cmd = "python/";
    String py = "file";
    String run = "python  " +cmd+ py + ".py";
    System.out.println(run);
    //Runtime.getRuntime().exec(run);

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python  file.py");
```

Either using variable run, or the whole path or "python file.py" my code is running showing the message build successful total time 0 seconds without execute the file.py. What is my problem here?

Comment: ‘Build successful’ sounds like the result of a *compilation*. How are you running this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Run a Python file from Java using an Absolute Path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081898/how-to-run-a-python-file-from-java-using-an-absolute-path)

Comment: I run it either with the play button or right click and run file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use like this also:

```
String command = "python /c start python path\to\script\script.py";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command + param );
```

or

```
String prg = "import sys";
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("path/a.py"));
out.write(prg);
out.close();
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python path/a.py");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String ret = in.readLine();
System.out.println("value is : "+ret);
```

**[Run Python script from Java](http://bytes.com/topic/python/insights/949995-three-ways-run-python-programs-java)**

Comment: What is param variable? I run this one  String c = "python c start python influencersDataset_edgelist.py";
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(c); but the same it just build in 0 seconds.

Comment: @FereRes param means if you want to send a parameter in script so this is the way...

Comment: Weird if I copy python path\to\script\script.py to console it works fine, however here with pb it doesn't react.

Comment: Yes indeed. Finally I have checked that link and I found the solution.

Answer (score 10):

I believe we can use ProcessBuilder

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python "+cmd + py + ".py");
.....
//since exec has its own process we can use that
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("python", py + ".py");
builder.directory(new File(cmd));
builder.redirectError();
....
Process newProcess = builder.start();
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python" (in directory "python  python\file.py"): CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid. I tested the whole path but I got the same.

Comment: try changing the string to an array. I believe that will work.
`String[] cmd = new String[] {"python,"...",".."}`

Comment: Cannot run program "python " (in directory "python  C:\Users\path\file.py"): CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid. I use String[] command = new String[]{"python ", cmd+py+".py"};

Answer (score 6):

```
String command = "cmd /c python <command to execute or script to run>";
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    p.waitFor();
    BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader bre = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
          String line;
        while ((line = bri.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
          }
          bri.close();
          while ((line = bre.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
          }
          bre.close();
          p.waitFor();
          System.out.println("Done.");

    p.destroy();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can run the python script

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(PYTHON_ABSOLUTE_PATH, script_path)
```

To get the PYTHON_ABSOLUTE_PATH just type

```
which python2.7
```

in terminal

Answer (score 2):

Though the OP has got the answer, I'm posting my solution which might help someone else like me..

```
        File file = new File(("C:/.../file.py"));

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("python.exe");
        String absPath = file.getAbsolutePath();

        System.out.println("absPath>>"+absPath);

        list.add(absPath);
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(list);
        Process process = pb.start();

        InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
        byte[] b = new byte[1024 * 1024];// {(byte) 1024};
        while (inputStream.read(b) > 0) {
            System.out.println("b.length>>"+new String(b));
        }

        process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("exitValue()>>"+process.exitValue());    //Should return 0 on successful execution
```