# Receive output of python program in java

Tags: java, python, windows

I've a Python program which just prints "hello world". I only want to get that output in a Java program and print that again, i.e. I want to consume output of Python program in a Java program.

I tried using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("helloworld.py");` but it is giving an exception saying `java.lang.IOException : Cannot run program "helloworld.py" : CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application`.

Can anybody please explain why this exception has occurred and what is solution for it ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well it's inside the tin what it says on the outside! A python File can't be a COMPILED WIN32 APPLICATION!

Comment: You should run python and give `"helloworld.py" as a parameter.

Comment: exec need an exe file. not a py file.

Comment: I'm using full path, no issues with that. "You should run python", what exactly does it suggest to do ? I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with python

Comment: Duplicated post. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267391/running-a-py-file-from-java

Comment: As far as I understand the former comments you may try with something like `.exec("python helloworld.py")`.

Comment: Do you have ".py" in environment variable "pathext"

Comment: @LouisZwawiak it worked, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this,

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python helloworld.py");`

Please try and if it doesn't work leave a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Your file "helloworld.py" isn't a executable file.

Your command allow to run a prompt command.

try : `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python helloworld.py");`

or see more :
[How do I run a Python program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522564/how-do-i-run-a-python-program)