# How to pass data from java to python script as parameter

Tags: java, python, parameter-passing

I wanted to run a script from java class. 
I was able to do it with `ProcessBuilder`. 
Now I am struggling to pass data as an argument to the script. I can pass a string, but I am having trouble passing list of data (data read from a CSV file).
One that I tried was using `StringBuffer` and passing the data as `Bytes`

```
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    ArrayList argsList = new ArrayList();

    // append the sb from record. 
    //convert it to bytes 
    //sb.toString() contains my data with a delimiter ';'

    // sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8").toString()

    argsList.add(0,"Continuum/anaconda3/envs/sth/python");
    argsList.add(1,"python/test.py");
    argsList.add(2,"python/test.py");
    argsList.add(3,sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8").toString())

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(argsList);

    Process p = builder.start();
```

I can not pass `sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")` to the process builder. 
I get `java.lang.ArrayStoreException`

On the other hand, if I pass `sb.toString()`, I get

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program Continuum/anaconda3/envs/sth/python, CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
add it to list of commands to process builder.
```

How can I read what I passed in python?

Is this even the right way to pass data ( row X column)?

Thanks

Comment: check this, it may be helpful since it does the same thing using a different approach , https://norwied.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/pass-arguments-from-java-to-python-app/

Comment: did u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267391/running-a-py-file-from-java/27267509

Comment: How long exactly is the string you are trying to pass? There's usually an OS-imposed limit on command line argument length on the order of maybe 100 kilobytes. Also, did you try making your `ArrayList` an `ArrayList<String>` to maybe fix whatever type confusion is giving you an `ArrayStoreException`?

Comment: How big is your `sb.toString()`? What does your test.py do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code ::

```
import java.io.*;

class RunPythonCommand {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        try {

            String prg = "import sys\nprint int(sys.argv[1])+int(sys.argv[2])\n";
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("sample_code.py"));
            out.write(prg);
            out.close();
            int param1 = 10;
            int param2 = 32;

            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", "sample_code.py", "" + param2, "" + param1);
            Process p = pb.start();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            int ret = new Integer(in.readLine()).intValue();
            System.out.println("value is : " + ret);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: param2 is an argument which is passed in sample_code.py . sample_code.py have a code of sum/multiplication code.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass args as array.:

final String PYTHON = "python";

final String SCRIPT_PATH =  new File("Pyscript.py").getPath();

final String ACTION = "-aexport";

final String[] CMD_ARRAY = {PYTHON, SCRIPT_PATH, ACTION};

ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(CMD_ARRAY);