# Running python script, as exe, with parameters, from Java

Tags: java, python, arguments, exe

I have found some tips on how to do that, but combining them together does not work, so i am asking for help.

I have a script in python, which gets it's variables from parameters(arguments?)(sys.argv). I have used PyInstaller to create an exe.

Now i need to open this file, with parameters, from java.

The problem is, i got the error: Failed to execute script [ScriptName].

This is my code from java:

```
try {
    ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder(Location, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4,
                                                arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9,
                                                arg10, arg11, arg12, arg13, arg14);
    Process proc = process.start();
    proc.waitFor();
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    //logging the result
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And this is my code in python:

```
arg1 = sys.argv[2]
arg2 = sys.argv[3]
arg3 = sys.argv[4]
arg4 = sys.argv[5]
arg5 = sys.argv[6]
(...)
```

I have tried different 'argv positions' (i.e. arg1 = sys.argv[1] etc.), but nothing works.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please look at the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267391/running-a-py-file-from-java/27267509

Comment: What is `Location`? Is it your script?

Comment: Location is location of the exe file (made by pyInstaller)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to compose a call String with all your arguments like this (you should use a StringBuilder or something similar for tidy code):

```
String call = "python yourscript.py argument1 argument2 argument3";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(call);
```

So far, this has always worked for me, without even needing an .exe. 
Also, you should be able to run an .exe the exact same way.

Answer (score 0):

None of the things mentioned have worked, i have decided to do it by txt file (writing txt in java and reading it in python).

I think that the best option would be to do pass the data by database, but in that case it was not an option :(

BTW. i also have tried getting values by argparse instead of sys.arg, but i think the problem was in java (The script was not even executed).