# Is there anyway to run python script in Ktor Framework?

Tags: python, kotlin, server, ktor

I'm using Ktor Framework to create the server.

I created a POST request that has the body structure like {"Image": "Image File"}. Now I need to process the received image using a Python Script.

Is there any way to run a python script in Ktor Framework?

Comment: Can you just run python command as a [separate process from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267391/running-a-py-file-from-java/27267509)? You might also want to try [jython](https://www.jython.org/) framework?

Comment: Running Kotlin in GRAAL VM also allows calling Python directly from Kotlin, assuming that the subset of Python they support covers your needs, and likely that does not work if the Python expects binary dependencies.