# Problem with executing a python file with few arguments in java

Tags: python, java

This is my java code that let me execute a python script.
The problem is everything is printed in the correct form but there is no creation for the file "test.txt" while executing with java.
[image: java script]
[image: python script]

If executing python script manually or from the cmd directly, everything works perfectly but not with java code

Comment: a) do not post code as images.  b) do not silently ignore exceptions c) I do not think there is a `python` program, at least `python.exe`  d) where do you expect `test.txt` to be created and why?

Comment: Show code as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: Use the complete executable path of Python.
Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55603110/15400163

Comment: The creation of the file should take place relative to the "working directory", which likely where ever Eclipse executed the program from

Comment: Don't write your entire program within the `try` block and you might see the error by yourself. This is very bad programming style.

Comment: Please edit the question to include your code as ```Your Code``` to make it clear. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Correct your `cmd /c python` with your correct python path (i can't know for sure that, but it will sure end with `python.exe`, not just `python`).

You don't see errors because you are catching exceptions (generate for example by a wrong path) without handling them, rendering them silent.