# BufferedReader - Entire output gets printed

Tags: java, python

I'm trying to print the output of a python file in Java.

The python file is basically a web scraper - there are multiple functions in it,each containing some lines of output. So the output should come in a sequence, one after another. Each line of output has to come in a regular interval(as per code), not all together.
The code below prints the output but I get the output as a single text,only after the entire program run.

```
public class Samtest extends Thread {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  String pythonScriptPath0 = "IR_Component_module11.py";
  String[] cmd0 = new String[2];
  cmd0[0] = "C:\\Python27\\python.exe";
  cmd0[1] = pythonScriptPath0;
  Runtime rt0 = Runtime.getRuntime();
  java.lang.Process pr0 = rt0.exec(cmd0);
  BufferedReader bfr0 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr0.getInputStream()));
  String line0 = "";
  while((line0 = bfr0.readLine()) != null)
  {
    System.out.println(line0);
  }

 }
}
```

I need the output to come naturally as per the program run . But I get the entire output after the program run.The scraper consists of a GUI. So only when I exit the GUI do I get the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Python buffers the output. Use `-u`

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Samtest extends Thread {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String pythonScriptPath0 = "IR_Component_module11.py";
        String[] cmd0 = new String[3];
        cmd0[0] = "C:\\Python27\\python.exe";
        cmd0[1] = "-u";
        cmd0[2] = pythonScriptPath0;
        Runtime rt0 = Runtime.getRuntime();
        java.lang.Process pr0 = rt0.exec(cmd0);
        BufferedReader bfr0 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr0.getInputStream()));
        String line0 = "";
        while ((line0 = bfr0.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line0);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Threading won't help. The java programme will still wait for the python script to finish its execution. Try executing the python script that I provided in my answer. The output will come altogether rather than first printing 'Hello' and waiting for 2 seconds and then printing 'TimeUp'.

Comment: @pss Sorry - you are right. It's the output buffer of python. I have changed the code. Thanks for your code review

Comment: @drkunibar Using -u sorts out the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The output that you are receiving is being created/generated by the python script, then this output is delivered to your java programme which finally prints its. If the python script has not completed its execution you cannot receive its output. So, your java programme waits for the python script to finish its execution and then it retrieves the output from your python script and finally prints it. This is the reason why you get the output when you close the GUI.

Try it with a simple python script. Create a python script with the following content:

```
import time
print 'Hello'
time.sleep(2)
print 'TimeUp'
```

If you execute this script using python, then you may see that it first prints `Hello` and then after `2` seconds it prints `TimeUp`. But when you execute this same script using your java programme. You shall see the entire output altogether. Because your java programme will wait for the python script to complete. I hope now you understand the reason. *Using threads is not going to solve this problem*.

Execution sequence in your case is: python-script -----> Java-programme -----> Console-output

[image: execution]

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102989/java-is-there-a-way-to-run-a-system-command-and-print-the-output-during-executi) is an interesting question that may help you further.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply! I understand the reason behind the output coming all together!