# Get BufferedReader.readLine() to wait for input

Tags: java, process, bufferedreader, processbuilder

I have a Python server that I start with a Java ProcessBuilder thread. The Java program should wait until the server is ready before proceeding. When the server is ready, it outputs a "Server-ready" message, which I assume is picked up by the Process object's InputStream.

```
START_SERVER_COMMAND = TAGGERFLOW_HOME + "server.py";
server = new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO().command("python", START_SERVER_COMMAND, "" + portNum,
        config.featOrderName(), config.childOrderName(), "" + maxBeta).start();
System.out.println("Hypertagger server started");
LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Hypertagger server started");

String line = null;
while(line == null) {
    line = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream())).readLine();
    if(line == null)
        Thread.sleep(5000);
}
System.out.println("Exit loop");
```

However, `line` is always null, and so Java never exits the loop. That most likely indicates that my assumption about the InputStream picking up the "Server-ready" message is wrong, but I don't know why that would be the case.

I'm looking for either a way to pick up the "Server-ready" message or a better way to detect when the server is ready. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT

Before this, I tried initializing the BufferedReader before the loop. It had the same behavior.

Comment: So, you're saying that there is no output been generated by the python `Process`? Maybe have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102989/java-is-there-a-way-to-run-a-system-command-and-print-the-output-during-executi/19103198#19103198) which links to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-print-function) which might provide some insights

Comment: I added a `sys.stdout.flush()` line at the end of the Python server setup function. It now prints "Server ready", but Java is still stuck in the infinite loop.

Comment: You should definitely initialize `BufferedReader` *before* the loop, otherwise you're going to lose part of output, once you fix the [real error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51814283/5221149), of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*TL;DR:* If you want your Java program to capture the output, don't redirect the output elsewhere, i.e. don't call `inheritIO()`, though you might want to call [`redirectErrorStream(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream-boolean-).

---

What do you think [`inheritIO()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO--) does?

> Sets the source and destination for subprocess standard I/O to be the same as those of the current Java process.
>
> This is a convenience method. An invocation of the form
>
> ```
> pb.inheritIO()
> ```
>
> behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation
>
> ```
> pb.redirectInput(Redirect.INHERIT)
>   .redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT)
>   .redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT)
> ```

When I/O is redirected, what do you think [`getInputStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream--) does?

> Returns the input stream connected to the normal output of the subprocess. The stream obtains data piped from the standard output of the process represented by this `Process` object.
>
> If the standard output of the subprocess has been redirected using `ProcessBuilder.redirectOutput` then **this method will return a [null input stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirect-output)**.

Should be obvious, but what is a *null input stream*?

> a destination for *standard output* and *standard error*. By default, the subprocess writes standard output and standard error to pipes. Java code can access these pipes via the input streams returned by `Process.getInputStream()` and `Process.getErrorStream()`. However, standard output and standard error may be redirected to other destinations using `redirectOutput` and `redirectError`. In this case, `Process.getInputStream()` and/or `Process.getErrorStream()` will return a *null input stream*, for which:
>
> - the `read` methods always return `-1`
> - the `available` method always returns `0`
> - the `close` method does nothing